# ckeditor in Drupal 8 custom module

Tags: ckeditor, drupal-8

I am currently developing a custom module for Drupal 8.
While adding a backend form to get some data from users I tried to get the ckeditor configured to replace my textareas... and failed >.<

here is the form definition:

```
    $form['text'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textarea',
        '#title' => t('Text'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'text',
            'style' => 'max-width: 650px'
        ),
        '#default_value' => $data['text']
    );
```

where do I need to load the ckeditor to replace my textarea?

things I already tried:

```
$build['#attached'] = array(
        'js' => array(
          drupal_get_path('module', 'ckeditor') . '/js/ckeditor.js'
drupal_render($build);
```

and

```
drupal_load_library("ckeditor", "ckeditor");
```

but I can't load all the dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the Drupal 8 form API which has a [text_format](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/8#text_format) form type. A check on your **#default_value** is also recommended.

Navigate to **Configuration > Content authoring > Text formats and editors** giving you an overview of the current available text formats. The ones listed here can be used in the **#format** proprty of your form field. (Default fallback currently is `basic_html`)

Try to change your code to:

```
$form['text'] = array(
    '#type' => 'text_format',
    '#title' => t('Text'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => isset($data['text']) ? $data['text'] : '',
    '#format' => 'full_html',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but had issues saving the data with above solution. In the end it looked like this:

```
$form['body'] = [
      '#type' => 'text_format',
      '#title' => $this->t('Body'),
      '#description' => $this->t('Message'),
      '#default_value' => $config->get('body'),
      '#format' => 'full_html',
    ];
```

and in submitForm method I save config like so

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);

    $this->config('my_module.default')
      ->set('body', $form_state->getValue('body')['value'])
      ->save();
  }
```

Note the reference to the attached ['value'] array.